# Can not edit script (Unity3D)

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

[image: image 1]

I want to edit "SeverLink" script, but it looks a bit strange...

[image: image 2]

when I click edit script, it show a empty inspector...

---

Is this some kind of a special mechanism?

What should I do to edit "SeverLink" script?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the ServerLink and following scripts are embedded in a dll. If thats the case you can't easily edit them if you dont have access to the source files.
There are some decompilers out there, but i dont think thats what you want to do.